# Minor GUI issues: the tag deletion button

Tags: bug, design

I just posted a posted something, and I noticed that the little "x" on the tag names which suppose to delete the tag from the current tag list is not fully included in the tag box itself.

(This is similar, and in addition, to the bounty free form dialog problem that I posted on Tea before the migration.)

I am using Firefox 21/Arch Linux 64bit.

[image: issue]

Comment: Confirmed on this post (click [edit]). Debian Linux, IceWeasel 21.

Comment: @Sklivvz: So I'm not imagining this. Good.

Comment: Reproed on XP+Chrome

Comment: @Sklivvz: Maybe [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I pushed a fix for this. The change will be on live server after our next production build(within 24hrs).

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there any change to fix the bounty dialog issue as well? (see [this](http://i.imgur.com/XHoIPRD.jpg).)